# How to format html input to a certain format while passing an array to php post data

Tags: php, html, arrays, conditional-formatting

I am working on this Html project and need to take in a list of a last name, first name, Id#, and a list of values (comma separated) up to 50 characters, and in the format of
"0.0 to 100.0."

```
<td>List of values: </td><td><input type="text" name="listOfValues"  maxlength="50" />
</tr>
```

I am trying to think up a pattern to meet those conditions to the user. In my post data I have sent that information to an exploded array here is my code for the PHP:

```php
$valuesList = explode(',', $_POST['listOfValues']);
//condition to check if any of these variables are empty
if( empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($userID) || empty($valuesList) ) {
    echo '<p style="color:red"> Please, Fill the text box before submitting data!</p>';
} else {
    $path ="UserInfo.txt";
    //fo = the open version of the UserInfo.txt file
    $fo = fopen($path, 'a') or die('Cannot open file'); 
    $maxOfList = max($valuesList);
    $minOfList = min($valuesList);

    // so if these variables are filled correctly then the machine will print them into the UserInfo.txt file
    fwrite($fo, "| Last Name: ".$lname. "| ");
    fwrite($fo, "| First Name: ".$fname. "| ");
    fwrite($fo, "| UserID: ".$userID. "| ");
    fwrite($fo, "| Minimum: " . $minOfList. "| ");
    fwrite($fo, "| Maximum: " . $maxOfList. "| ". "\n");
    // fwrite($fo, "Values: ".$valuesList. " " ."\n");
    fclose($fo);
```

When sent the following information, [Info Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZE46.png) the txt file displays the following : " | Last Name: Batson| | First Name: Billy| | UserID: abc123| | Minimum: 1| | Maximum: 81| " which is correct but, I need it to only allow decimals in the format of "0.0 - 100.0" per entry and no negatives. Is there any way for this to work through the html pattern tag or do I need some form of php statements in my php file to error check my lists? (assume the tags are in the right place please)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to filter each input.

Assuming `$_POST['listOfValues']` is the following string: `"90, 100, 50.0, 100.56"`

```php
// Using str_replace to remove all spaces.
$valuesList = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['listOfValues'])); 
// $valuesList should now be equal to array("90", "100", "50.0", "100.56")

if (empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($userID) || empty($valuesList) ) {
    echo '<p style="color:red"> Please, Fill the text box before submitting data!</p>';
} elseif (! validateFormat($valuesList) ) {
    echo '<p style="color:red"> The values should be in the format 90.0, 50.0</p>'; 
} else {
    ...
    // Turn the $valueList array back into a string separating the values with ', '
    $values = implode(', ', $valuesList);
    // Append $values to file.
    fwrite($fo, "Values: ".$values. " " ."\n");
}

// returns true if every element of the array $valueList in the format 
// (numbers) + (.) + (single number) AND they are between 0.0 and 100.0 (inclusive)
// returns false otherwise
function validateFormat(array $valueList) : bool {
    return array_reduce($valueList, function ($carry, $item) {
        return $carry && preg_match('/^\d+\.\d{1}$/', $item) && ((float) $item >= 0.0) && ((float) $item >= 100.0);
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: where do I need to insert this code for it to work? because it is giving me fatal errors when I use it saying that the "..." is invalid and that validateFormat() is not real. Any fixes or advice there?

Comment: The ... was not a part of the code. It's where the rest of your code would be